# Is there a way to listen to an event from Directive when form has been reset?

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there a way to **listen from Directive** when form has been reset by using an **event or lifeCycle Hook**?

I have this form that looks like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit($event)">
  <input type="text" formControlName="firstName" myDirective/>
  <button id="btnClear" (click)="onReset($event)">Clear</button>
</form>
```

**My Component:**

```
   @Component({
     selector: 'app-form',
     templateUrl: './app-form.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./app-form.component.scss']
   })
   export class AppSearchFormComponent implements OnInit {

   myForm: FormGroup;

   constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder, private store: Store<any>) { }

   ngOnInit() {
   this.createForm();
   }

   createForm(){
       this.myForm = this._fb.group({
       'firstName': ['', [Validators.minLength(2)]]
    });
   }

 onReset(evt) {
  this.myForm.reset();
  }
 }
```

**My custom Directive:**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myDirective]'
})
export class CustomDirective {

   constructor(private el: ElementRef, private control : NgControl) { }

     @HostListener('someEvent',['$event'])
      onkeyup(event:any){

       console.log('Yes Form has been reset!); // I want to display this message
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **NgControl**

> A base class that all control FormControl-based directives extend. It
>   binds a FormControl object to a DOM element.

Inject NgControl in directive constructor then use the valuechanges method to subscribe the changes

```
import { Directive} from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';
@Directive({
  selector: '[reset]',
})
export class ResetDirective {
  constructor(private ngControl: NgControl) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    const reset$ = this.ngControl.control.valueChanges;
    reset$.subscribe((e) => {
      if (e === null) {
        console.log('Yes Form has been reset!');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/reset-directive